# Close modalpopup inside another modalpopup

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, modalpopupextender

I have a problem a few days ago that I cannot solve:

I have a modals popups extender from asp.net  that when pressed on a button opens another popup (if something changes, both are users controls only).

The problem arises at the close of the second. I am currently using:

```
modalpopup.Dispose ()
```

When you do this, the modal pop up leaves, causing the first to stop responding.

If you need, I can attach some part of the code that can guide you. Thank you!

Comment: What is a `modalpopup`? What UI Framework are you referring to? Add the required tags to your question.

Comment: Sorry, i already edit the question. Is a modal popup extender from asp.net